# getActivity(), getContext(), getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext(), activity.this, this :all returning NULL (not a duplicate of NullPointerExcept)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I have an activity called FiltersAndEditActivity and two fragments inside it. Inside one of the fragments I am running the following code:

```
public void prepareThumbnail(final Bitmap bitmap) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Bitmap thumbImage;

                if (bitmap == null) {
                    thumbImage = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromAssets(getActivity(), FiltersAndEditActivity.IMAGE_NAME, 100, 100);
                } else {
                    thumbImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, false);
                }

                if (thumbImage == null)
                    return;

                ThumbnailsManager.clearThumbs();

                // add normal bitmap first
                ThumbnailItem thumbnailItem = new ThumbnailItem();
                thumbnailItem.image = thumbImage;
                thumbnailItem.filterName = "normal";
                ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(thumbnailItem);

                List<Filter> filters = FilterPack.getFilterPack(activity);

                for (Filter filter : filters) {
                    ThumbnailItem tI = new ThumbnailItem();
                    tI.image = thumbImage;
                    tI.filter = filter;
                    tI.filterName = filter.getName();
                    ThumbnailsManager.addThumb(tI);
                }

                thumbnailItemList.addAll(ThumbnailsManager.processThumbs(context));

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        new Thread(r).start();
    }
```

processThumbs method code (inside a Util class named ThumbnailManager):

```
public static List<ThumbnailItem> processThumbs(Context context) {
    for (ThumbnailItem thumb : filterThumbs) {
        // scaling down the image
        float size = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.thumbnail_size);
        thumb.image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumb.image, (int) size, (int) size, false);
        thumb.image = thumb.filter.processFilter(thumb.image);
        // cropping circle

        // TODO - think about circular thumbnails
        // thumb.image = GeneralUtils.generateCircularBitmap(thumb.image);
        processedThumbs.add(thumb);
    }
    return processedThumbs;
}
```

FiltersAndEditActivity code where I am calling prepareThumbmail method of fragment:

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapterr adapter = new ViewPagerAdapterr(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // adding filter list fragment
        filtersListFragment = new FiltersListFragment();
        filtersListFragment.setListener(this);

        // adding edit image fragment
        editImageFragment = new EditImageFragment();
        editImageFragment.setListener(this);

        adapter.addFragment(filtersListFragment, getString(R.string.tab_filters));
        adapter.addFragment(editImageFragment, getString(R.string.tab_edit));

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapterr extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapterr(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    

private void setImage(){
        intent = getIntent();
        FiltersListFragment filtersListFragment = new FiltersListFragment();

        if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))){
            imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
            Log.d(TAG, "setImage: got new image url: " + imgUrl);
            originalImage = ImageManager.getBitmap(imgUrl);
            filteredImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            finalImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
            filtersListFragment.prepareThumbnail(originalImage);
        }

    }
```

But getActivity(), getContext(), activity.this, simply this : all are returning null on this line: ThumbnailManager.processThumbs(getContext). Earlier, activity.runOnUiThread() was also returning null but no idea how it got fixed. I have tried some solutions on similar questions but none of them have worked so far. Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: it can occur when your fragment is detached from you activity then it will return getActivity(), getContext() instead try requireContext() or requireActivity() which will throw exception if context or activity is null. so you can find out issue easily.

Comment: Where are you calling `prepareThumbnail()` method?

Comment: @Manohar in the activity

Comment: @Bhavin yes I tried that and the logcat says : IllegalStateException : Fragment not attached to an activity/context. But I just don't know how to proceed. Tried solutions on similar questions but none of them worked.

Comment: @KrishnaJindal can you share the code where you create your fragment which contains this method as well when you attach, cause as i can see you're directly trying to use method of your fragment which is not attached to the activity.

Comment: @Bhavin Edited my code. Please check.

Comment: where is the `prepareThumbnail()` method ?

Comment: @KrishnaJindal i have added the answer, still if you're having doubt you can ask. and i don't know the whole scenario so i have added the answer as per current context but you can make changes to make it more readable and reusable (if required).

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned earlier, this error is occurring due to Fragment is not attached to any activity.

```
private void setImage(){
    intent = getIntent();
    FiltersListFragment filtersListFragment = new FiltersListFragment();
    
    // it will add filterListFragment into container and container is defined in your current activity xml file where you want to show this fragment
    getSupportedFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.container, filtersListFragment)
         .commit();

    if(intent.hasExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image))){
        imgUrl = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image));
        Log.d(TAG, "setImage: got new image url: " + imgUrl);
        originalImage = ImageManager.getBitmap(imgUrl);
        filteredImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        finalImage = originalImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        imagePreview.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
        filtersListFragment.prepareThumbnail(originalImage);
    }

}
```

**Some references:**

[How to use fragment](https://medium.com/@anandh51295/how-to-use-fragment-in-activity-android-application-c494433e26fc)

[Adding fragment programmatically](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add)

#### Edit

as viewpager is being used and its different issue then previous so i'm adding other answer here

in your activity you're shadowing fragment object which leads to this error as the new fragment is not attached to activity still you're trying to call it's method. so make following changes to make it working.

```
private void setImage(){
    intent = getIntent();
    // we have to remove below line as it create new object of FiltersListFragment instead we use the same object as defined in setupViewPager() method
    //FiltersListFragment filtersListFragment = new FiltersListFragment();

    ....

}
```

Comment: Still the same error :(  I have edited my Activity code again, you might want to check that.

Comment: @KrishnaJindal it's reference issue, you're creating new FilterListFragment which is shadowing original object which is being added to ViewPager.

Comment: as you said @Bhavin , I removed that line. But now the error is "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void Fragments.FiltersListFragment.prepareThumbnail(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference which means filtersListFragment object is null but as you know, I have already initialised it in ViewPager. Dunno what is going on seriously!!!

Comment: i think you should debug your activity and how each and every method is being called and you can also pass the argument into your fragment using bundle so try considering it, as of your current flow there can be many issue.